# how to fix sssd segfault on ubuntu 18.04.02?

Tags: sssd

I've got an Ubuntu 18.04.02 server running samba and sssd with a decent load on it, between 300-400 active users during the day.  I put it in Sunday, and it has worked fine until today the system completely stopped responding.  The console would accept a root logon, but never display the shell.

I rebooted it and got it working, and found this in the kernel log:

```
Mar 20 13:49:52 fileserver kernel: [235224.207130] sssd_nss[2136]: segfault at a4 ip 00007fb9e3f5f629 sp 00007ffcb635c7e0 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.4[7fb9e3f34000+4b000]
Mar 20 13:49:52 etsfs05 kernel: [235224.207136] Code: 8d 3d 5b 0f 01 00 48 83 ec 08 b9 c1 02 00 00 e8 7d 1b 00 00 31 c0 48 83 c4 08 c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 83 ec 08 48 85 ff 74 57 <8b> 47 04 85 c0 78 30 8b 47 08 85 c0 74 29 89 f2 83 e2 fe a8 01 0f
```

Does anyone know of a way to keep this from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

You might check if https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1283769#c6 ("there is a workaround available of either moving the cache to tmpfs or increasing the 'timeout' option in the [domain] section.") helps.